# Filled wrong answer for a question in a previous 1040NR form, do I need to send amendment?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1040x

I filled my first tax form in 2013 -- **form 8843**. But the next year (2014) while I was filling the **form 1040NR**, when asked ***"Did you file a U.S. income tax return for any prior year?"***, I forgot that I filled a form 8843 before, and didn't fill in that blank. Now that I realized I filled this question wrongly, do I need to send an amendment to correct this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form 8843 is not an income tax return. I don't think you need to file an amendment.